# Why is bitcoin better than other electronic banking, like Dwolla or Paypal?

Tags: banks, dwolla

Why is bitcoin better than [Dwolla](https://www.dwolla.com/) or Paypal?

Comment: http://bitcoinmedia.com/bulleted-advantages/

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is Bitcoin?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3262/what-is-bitcoin)

Answer (score 6):

You don't need anyone's permission to use it. Nobody can freeze your account or charge back a payment after you received it. It's accessible to anyone with Internet access regardless of what country they're in. No single company can dictate its policy. It is almost free to use with no proportional fees.