# Where and how can I buy shares in bitcoin?

Tags: securities

Where can I buy shares of bitcoin? I have exhausted all due diligence as to where I can invest in Bitcoin.

Comment: It sounds like your due diligence has not lead to an understanding of what Bitcoin actually *is*.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. If you mean to ask where you can buy bitcoins you might want to take a look at [How do you obtain bitcoins?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/91/how-do-you-obtain-bitcoins). If you actually want to buy shares in Bitcoin, you might want to google "Winklevoss Bitcoin ETF", I think it is supposed to do something along that lines. If my trouble understanding your question's intent still seems odd to you, you might want to read [What is Bitcoin?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3262/what-is-bitcoin). If it is just me being dense, carry on.

Comment: And actually the "due diligence" also did not make him go to google, or use WIkipedia, both would have let to at least a basic understanding. No wonder society goes down if that is the level of due diligence these days. Hint - tell me where I Can buy some "shares in US DOllars".

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to "invest" in Bitcoin, there are a few places you can do it.

1. Buy bitcoins themselves. Arguably the easiest option
2. Buy hashing power and/or hardware. This can make you money in the meantime and has a very small chance of selling for more than you bought it, depending on hardware
3. Invest in the companies building hashing power(ASICs)

Answer (score 0):

MtGox is most likely your easiest route. Buy bitcoins. I don't recommend mining at this point unless you're feeling technically competent and risky. You can also try tranfering funds from Dwolla to CampBX.

https://www.mtgox.com/

https://campbx.com/‎