# What exactly are Bitcoins?

Tags: buy-bitcoins, sell-bitcoins

I've heard the term several times. I know that it's an online currency, but I'd like to know more, without having to search too hard.

My main questions:

What can bitcoins be used for?
Where does one acquire bitcoins?
When were they first created?

Comment: I'd downvote that question so hard.

Comment: It's advised that you make only one question per entry, so that people can focus on answering only that question.

Comment: duplicate of: [What exactly are Bitcoins?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3262/what-is-bitcoin), 
[What can Bitcoins be used for?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/91/how-do-you-obtain-bitcoins)
[When were they first created?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/182/where-do-bitcoins-come-from-and-what-gives-them-their-value)
I don't think the second question has been asked. You might want to [re-ask it](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score -2):

> What exactly are Bitcoins?

bitcoins are the right and possiblility to write some data (transaction) to some database (blockchain) passing this right to another person.

> What can bitcoins be used for?

What can gold be used for? Trading/exchanging for all other things

> Where does one acquire bitcoins?

Where does one acquire gold? Either buy it, or mine it, or steal it, or find it

> When were they first created?

When gold was first created? Dumb question. Just think that it exists today

Comment: So, bitcoins are gold? Virtual gold?

Comment: You can replace "gold" in my answer with "silver", "water" or even "bullshit". This does not matter.

Comment: Downvoted. You can choose not to answer, possibly asking to close the question for being poorly researched; but I don't find it legitimate to answer rudely. In particular, "When were they first created?" is not a dumb question. The answer depends on your notion of "created", but I'd say January 3 2009.

Comment: @MeniRosenfeld I'd argue that they were created over the course of two years prior to the announcement of Bitcoin.