# What gives bitcoins value? What are bitcoins backed by?

Tags: economic-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where do bitcoins come from and what give them its value?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/182/where-do-bitcoins-come-from-and-what-give-them-its-value)

Often times people ask (shortly after muttering something beanie babies), What gives bitcoins value? What are they backed by?