# How sign the first transaction's signature?

Tags: transactions, private-key, signature

[image: A chain of transactions]

In bitcoin, each transaction's signature is signed with previous owner's private key. Then, how sign the first transaction's signature?

Comment: related: [What is the coinbase?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/4571/5406), [Where do bitcoins come from and what gives them their value?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/182/5406)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Byte-map of transaction]

See [Bitcoin Wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction).
Above image illustrates a byte-map of transaction with each type of TxIn and TxOut.

We should attention at "Coinbase/Generation" (Coinbase means the first transaction in a block).
Codebase's script is a arbitary data.
Yep, it is **random**.

Therefore the signature of first transaction of a block is not used.