# process to list cryptocoins in exchangers

Tags: currencies

I have a cryptocoin which is 50% premined. I want to list it on exchangers. How can I do it? Please mention the process to list cryptocoins in exchangers and also where can I get the list of best 50 exchangers.

Comment: There isn't a single set process. I mean, cryptocurrencies don't have a right to be listed on an exchange by dint of existing.

Comment: I can't believe that username was still available.

Comment: @m1xolyd1an: Usernames are not unique on Stackexchange (and there was another user with that name before).

Comment: -1 I don't find this question useful, and it doesn't show any previous research. The asker should familiarize themselves with value of cryptocurrencies and how their ecosystem works. A good starting point might be: [Where do bitcoins come from and what gives them their value?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/182/5406)

Comment: Exchanges only list assets. Until your coin is an asset with a value, there's no reason for exchanges to list it.

Answer (score 0):

Lol. You're obviously trying to make your own coin to sell off as soon as it hits the market. Not good.

You will first have to build a userbase. Exchanges don't just accept anyone. If you have real supporters (Honestly I wouldn't support any premined coin, let alone one that's mined 50%).

Most exchanges accept one or two coins a week. To get your coin chosen, you need users to vote for your coin, or on some Exchanges like YoBit, pay a fee in bitcoin (say 1.5 bitcoin)

My recommendation if you are premining a coin just to sell it on an exchange, is to stop and reevaluate.