# What's the best way to introduce Bitcoin to the family and friends?

Tags: currencies, education

What's the best way to introduce Bitcoin to the family and friends?
Has anybody succesful experience in the topic?

Comment: What do you mean by 'best'? Best at convincing them to use Bitcoin, or best at educating them about it.

Comment: I guess both. Trying to find new ways to tell people without causing more confusion.

Comment: related: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-a-good-way-to-concisely-explain-bitcoin

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the best way. But what I do is talk about it all the time. And actually use the bitcoins. I mean purchase things with your bitcoin not trade with them on exchange networks.

I buy a new product with my bitcoins and use it in front of my friends and family. Those who are interested ask where I got it, and then ask how much I spent on it. My response is in bitcoins. eg it was just 0.10 bitcoins very decent deal. Or it is just 2 bitcoins.

I've found that when selling an idea of bitcoin by saying things like 0.10BTC is worth $60.00 today I tend to get strange looks. Like so you spend $60.00 on 10 cents? People have a hard time understanding concept of ForEx and values of money when comparing one currency with another. It is more successful when you buy something and explain that you purchased it with bitcoin.

Also Christmas is coming up. And I've made paper wallets loaded with bitcoins. And on the paper wallets I have a list of websites that accept bitcoins as payments. So it is like a gift card and it helps people get the idea of what bitcoin is.