# Will this assumption allow individual bitcoin tracking possible?

Tags: transactions

Fist bitcoins in, First out.

Will this assumption allow individual bitcoin tracking possible?

example,

```
Addresses A, B and C each has 50 BTC

Transactions, 

  tx1 - A > D - 10 BTC (D - 10 BTC)
  tx2 - B > D - 15 BTC (D - 25 BTC)
  tx3 - C > D - 20 BTC (D - 45 BTC)

  tx4 - D > E - 20 BTC (E - 20 BTC, D - 25 BTC)

  Now,
    D has none of BTC received from A, 5 BTC from B and 20 BTC from C
    E, fist 10 BTC was received from A, next 10 BTC was received from B
```

Comment: related question (1), http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/450/is-there-any-way-to-track-an-individual-bitcoin-or-satoshi

Comment: Yes, but it's not a meaningful metric, if, say, the bitcoins were sold.

Comment: Would you do this for transaction fees as well?

Comment: transaction fees? yes, but only if it is > 1 satoshi. :)

Answer (score 3):

This is only true if one does not mix transactions. Otherwise you will have coins that are for example 50% from source A, 10% from B, 40% from C and so forth.

Comment: you are right. mixing services only could make it very difficult. blockchain doesn't know anything about intermediate addresses.

Comment: @vi.su. If someone set up a mixing service properly to completely separate various coins, it would be nearly untraceable, or at least highly deniable.