# Simple bitcoin mining algorithm

Tags: algorithms

I'm trying to figure out how does simple Bitcoin mining algorithm works in plain simple c or c#  or some pseudo language. I've found an example at http://pastebin.com/EXDsRbYH, but unfortunately It isn't clear what it does. I was unable to run it.

Suppose I have only one input: a Bitcoin wallet "abc..." which I would like to be used for the Bitcoins to be mined. I need simple to understand algorithm that will do the bitcoin mining on one machine with one thread on one cpu [I know it will take ages to complete :)]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The simplest miner would work like this:

1. Request a new [Getwork](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Getwork) from a given pool/bitcoind with specified credentials
2. For nonce=0;nonce<0xFFFFFFFF;nonce++

   - Set Getwork Data nonce
   - SHA-256 hash the Getwork Data ([block header](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_specification#Block_Headers))
   - Check if hash result is smaller than Getwork Target, if so, submit a share
   - If more than 1 second passed since you received Getwork, stop the loop
3. GOTO: 1

Now, if you want something that could rise up to par with currently used miners, you need to consider:

- [OpenCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) calculations, without this you will never get the high hashrates of graphic cards.
- Midstate, or in other words hashing optimization. First half of Getwork Data doesn't change, so no point in calculating midstate for each hash.
- [Longpolling](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Getwork#longpoll), makes you calculate less stale blocks.
- [Rollntime](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Getwork#rollntime), minimizes communication with the pool.

Comment: Could you please explain why we need to stop the loop if it took more than 1 second?

Comment: @Rasoul The basic getwork requests (in bitcoind) time out after 1 second as far as I remember. This is why we have to stop the loop and get new work every second.

Answer (score 2):

Read the answers to [this question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/148/what-exactly-is-mining) and if you have any specific questions about the mining algorithm perhaps you can edit your question to ask them.

If all you want to do is run a mining program, there are lots available.  You can study the source and see what they're doing.

The official bitcoin client itself has a basic CPU miner built in.  You can [examine the code](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/142e604184e3ab6dcbe02cebcbe08e5623182b81/src/main.cpp#L3352) to get an idea of how mining works.