# What kind of problems are solved when mining?

Tags: mining-theory

I am new to bitcoin. Before I decide to buy the hardware/software I want to know about kind of problems solved. And more importantly do I need to be skilled in any specific area (like mathematics or know of any software coding languages etc).

So my basic question is once I purchase the hardware and software and join a bitcoin pool, will I be assigned a specific problem to solve a problem by myself? OR is it just that my hardware/CPU is used to solve the mining problem(and I need not do any coding etc).

Thanks for any help or references.

Comment: -1 Question shows no previous research, has a nondescript title, and it is hard to tell what is being asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you do some reading:

[Bitcoin.org - Getting started](http://bitcoin.org/en/getting-started)

[Bitcoin.org - How it works](http://bitcoin.org/en/how-it-works)

[Bitcoin.it - Gettin started](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Getting_started)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to take some time and do some reading about what Bitcoin is.

Ask yourself, What are your goals with Bitcoin? Do you intend to simply own bitcoin? Why do you want to own it?

If your answer is, you want to own it because everyone is getting into it, you may want to reconsider what your trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your hardware will do the work for you and you won't have to do any coding.

I believe that this question will be a good read for you: [What exactly is mining?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/148/what-exactly-is-mining)