# Random numbers using blockchain

Tags: blockchain, block, hash, random

How are the block hashes generated?

Are they trully 100% random (generated by hardware) or is it pseudo-random (generated by software)?

Can i rely on it or any other blockchain data to make a 100% trustable raffle?

Regards,

Comment: Your first question: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/148/what-exactly-is-mining

Comment: You might want to check this open source raffle that relies on blockchain data: http://bitraffle.info/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are they truly 100% random (generated by hardware) or is it pseudo-random (generated by software)?

Pedantic answer: No, they're not random, because the first twenty digits or so will always be zero.

Serious answer: The Bitcoin client does not use any hardware randomness, as far as I know. However, if even a single transaction in the block was generated using hardware randomness, the block hash will incorporate hardware randomness.

Also, I don't think you could predict the hash of a block that hasn't been found yet.

> Can I rely on it or any other blockchain data to make a 100% trustable raffle?

As Greg said, a miner can withhold blocks if releasing them would make the miner lose the raffle. Of course, the cost of withholding a block and not broadcasting it to the network is about $9000, so this attack might not be useful.

> How do I make a trustable raffle

Your method would probably work. [This answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1644/6705) discusses how to exchange a secret between two parties that can't trust one another. You could use something based on that.

Answer (score 3):

> Are they trully 100% random (generated by hardware) or is it pseudo-random (generated by software)?

Actually, no, they are 0% random. There is no randomness involved in the mining process whatsoever. The only part in Bitcoin that involves a random generator is the creation of private keys.

As for the **unpredictability** of block hashes (which may appear to be some sort of random), this is because of the [avalanche effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalanche_effect) that is typical for cryptographic hash functions. From a practical point of view, you can consider block hashes to be random.

> Can i rely on it or any other blockchain data to make a 100% trustable raffle?

The block hashes, yes (although note that they're not perfectly 256-bit distributed, the first n bits are zero). Other blockchain data, probably not, as this can be influenced by others (e.g. miners deciding what transactions to include).

Answer (score 2):

Block hashes can be considered neither random nor pseudo-random. Miners can choose which transactions to include in a block, and don't have to broadcast every block they find. For example, a miner could refuse to broadcast a block unless the block hash ends in a 1 bit. This might not seem important, but it introduces a bias into the resulting block hash and therefore it cannot be considered "random".

In a similar way, none of the other data in a block can be safely considered truly random. Miners get to choose what data goes into each block (even the nonce).