# Mining against candidate block hash or previous block hash?

Tags: hash, proof-of-work, block-header

When mining...;

a) Is the block header hash of the **candidate** block used

b) OR the block header hash of the **previous** block + noonce used?

If it is a), which I presume, is it then correct that the procedure is;

- Write incremented noonce into the candidate block header
- Calculate the hash, which thus changed bc of the updated noonce, of the candidate block header and check against the target.

I looked but did not find any other question that covers exactly this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What exactly is Mining?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/148/what-exactly-is-mining)  -- I've read answers there from which I believe a reader could see that your presumption is correct.

Comment: Much appreciated, RedGrittyBrick! I'll post a follow-up question I have over there instead.